# Restore "k1:v1,k2:v2,.." from JSON value as Key-value pairs

Tags: c#, json, json.net, keyvaluepair

I have a JSON value like this and I need help specifically in putting the Value of D variable in a keyValuepair.

```
{"A":727657,"B":"72.74:hello","C":"Http","D":"Value:0,Value1:79,Value2:56,Value3:45","E":0,"F":2}
```

I am parsing this value like this.

```
   MyJSONContructor MyJSONContructorObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJSONContructor>(JSONValue);
```

I have a constructor like this.

```
public MyJSONContructor(int A, string B, string C, string D, bool E,int F)
        {
            this.A = A;
            this.B = B;
            this.C = C;
            this.D = D;
            this.E = E;
            this.F = F;
        }
```

What I need help with is the value in variable D, if you notice it has several values inside it, I want to be able to put them in a keyValuePair, something like this

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> contentsToPost
```

Is there an easy way to add them to the List of KeyValuePairs, since we would not know how many key value pairs would be coming in D in Json, I am trying to avoid doing something like this.

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { 
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Value", 0),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Value1", 79),
```

Comment: Does order matter? Otherwise you could use Dictionary<string, string>. Dictionary is a HashMap.

Comment: The 'direct' approach would be to use something like `D = d.Split(',').Select(p => p.Split(':', 2)).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1])` (or modified to exact need such as `.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x[0], x[1])).ToList()`). This is a one-way de-serialization only, Json.NET might provide more 'integral' methods.

Comment: Order really doesnt matter as long as right key and values are paired correctly

Comment: The thing that you are trying to parse is a good candidate for *Data structure of the year* award. And it's just June. ;) `</sarcasm>`

Comment: ok so that wont work because I need it in the format of List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comfortable with [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), you can do it like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvps = 
    (from pair in MyJSONContructorObject.D.Split(',')
     let kv = pair.Split(':')
     select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kv[0], kv[1])
    ).ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHti3s

Comment: Worked perfectly.. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
var myMap = new Dictionary<string,string>();
var rawArray = dValuesInSingleString.Split(',');

foreach(var arrayItem in rawArray)
{
    var keyAndValueArray = arrayItem.Split(':');
    myMap.Add(keyAndValueArray[0], keyAndValueArray[1]);
}
```

KeyValuePair is used inside Dictionary, so to get a list of KeyValuePairs, you could then do this:

```
var myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> k in myMap)
{
    myList.Add(k);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kira, I need to be able to assign it to an object of KeyValuePair List, how can I do about doing that?

Comment: Thanks so much Kira, this worked like a charm...Brian's code worked too. Thanks you so much guys.